# Что озачает конструкция .* в таблице стилей?

Tags: вёрстка, css

Верстальщики, приветствую!

В коде рабочего проекта, который перевожу на другой движок, в таблице стилей обнаружил конструкцию .*

[image]

Как могу догадываться, это определение для всех классов до или после данного селектора. Но дело в том, что на нее ругается мой NetBeans и распознает как ошибку. Верным понимает селектор * (без точки), но в этом случае едет верстка.

Кто с таким уже встречался, прошу объяснить, что означает данный селектор и есть ли аналогичные альтернативные конструкции?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нет такого стиля в css:

```
.* {
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
    height: 305px;
}
```

и такого тоже нет, даже если оно написано в каком-то кастомном исходнике шаблона, стиль этот просто не работает и всё:

```
. * {
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
    height: 305px;
}
```

При таких данных могут быть такие валидные варианты:

```
.class * { // Стиль будет применяться ко всем элементам внутри класса .class
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
    height: 305px;
}

* { // Стиль будет применяться вообще ко всем элементам на сайте
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
    height: 305px;
}

[class*="name"] { // Стиль будет применяться ко всем элементам, в классах которых встречается слово name, например, name-1, name-2, user-name и т.д.
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
    height: 305px;
}
```

Comment: Верная конструкция 
.class * {


}

Answer (score 1):

Понятное дело, что ругается. Видать кто-то хотел костыль приделать. После точки ожидается имя класса. Если под такой записью подразумевалось что-то вроде: "*стиль для элементов, у которых присутствует хоть какой-нибудь класс*", то можно записать так:

```
[class] {
  /* ... */
}
```

Comment: Попробовал изменить на [class], верстка поехала.